# How to make input text control ready for input on creationComplete in Flex/MXML?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, mxml

I have the following `Application` tag code in my widget:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
            xmlns:local="*"
            width="100%" height="100%" minWidth="200" minHeight="200" layout="absolute"
            creationComplete="init()" 
            defaultButton="{Send_btn}">
```

Input field is defined by

```
<mx:TextInput id="Input_txi" left="10" right="90" bottom="10"/>
```

Next I have the following at the end of `init()` method:

```
            Input_txi.setFocus();
            Input_txi.selectRange(0,0);
```

Nevertheless I can't enter any text just after the page is loaded. I see visually that `Input_txi` has focus, but keyprints do nothing. I need to click `Input_txi` before I can enter any text to it.

How to do so that I can start from the very beginning?

**EDIT 1**

Not worked, neither as in example, nor with jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // For version detection, set to min. required Flash Player version, or 0 (or 0.0.0), for no version detection. 
        var swfVersionStr = "${version_major}.${version_minor}.${version_revision}";
        // To use express install, set to playerProductInstall.swf, otherwise the empty string. 
        var xiSwfUrlStr = "${expressInstallSwf}";
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};
        params.quality = "high";
        params.bgcolor = "${bgcolor}";
        params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
        params.allowfullscreen = "true";
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.id = "${application}";
        attributes.name = "${application}";
        attributes.align = "middle";
        swfobject.embedSWF(
            "${swf}.swf", "flashContent", 
            "${width}", "${height}", 
            swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
            flashvars, params, attributes, function(){
                /*
                var swf = $("#" + attributes.id);
                swf.attr("tabindex", 0);
                swf.focus();
                */

                var f = swfobject.getObjectById(attributes.id);
                f.tabIndex = 0;
                f.focus();
            });
        // JavaScript enabled so display the flashContent div in case it is not replaced with a swf object.
        swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", "display:block;text-align:left;");

    </script>
```

Comment: `ExternalInterface` method worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the browser loads the page, the correct text input may have focus inside the SWF, but the SWF does not have focus inside the browser. There are a variety of different approaches for this, and I've provided a few links below.

[Automatically setting swf object focus](http://dougr.net/2011/07/05/automatically-setting-swf-object-focus/)

[Managing initial swf focus in all browsers](http://www.flexjunk.com/2010/12/30/managing-initial-swf-focus-in-all-browsers/)